# Resizing Google Hangouts app on Win 10 with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, google-hangouts

I need to resize Google Hangouts app in Win 10. through Autohotkey

Currently it is 260*460, and I need it to be 1150*750.

Here are the Window spy data:

```
>>>>>>>>>>( Window Title & Class )<<<<<<<<<<<
Hangouts
ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1

>>>>>>>>>>>>( Mouse Position )<<<<<<<<<<<<<
On Screen:  901, 600  (less often used)
In Active Window:   -759, 580

>>>>>>>>>( Now Under Mouse Cursor )<<<<<<<<

Color:  0xF0F0F0  (Blue=F0 Green=F0 Red=F0)

>>>>>>>>>>( Active Window Position )<<<<<<<<<<
left: 1660     top: 20     width: 260     height: 460

>>>>>>>>>>>( Status Bar Text )<<<<<<<<<<

>>>>>>>>>>>( Visible Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<
Chrome Legacy Window

>>>>>>>>>>>( Hidden Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<

>>>>( TitleMatchMode=slow Visible Text )<<<<

>>>>( TitleMatchMode=slow Hidden Text )<<<<
```

I tried something like the following, but it didn't work:

```
[code]
#Persistent
Loop
{

WinWaitActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
WinMove, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1, , 1150, 750

}

Return
[/code]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
; WinMove, WinTitle (or) ahk_class WinClass, WinText, X, Y , Width, Height, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText
WinMove, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1, , , , 1150, 750
```

Answer (score 1):

The WinMove command requires those arguments:

```
WinMove, WinTitle, WinText, X, Y [, Width, Height, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]
```

The arguments `WinText`, `X` and `Y` can be ommited in which case you leave them empty, but you still have to use the commas to indicate them.

You only left the argument `WinText` empty and the arguments with value 1150 and 750 got interpreted as arguments `X` and `Y`.

The solution is to add those two unused arguments `X` and `Y`:

```
WinMove, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1, , , , 1150, 750
```

If for example you want to also move the window to the positions 200, 100, then use the `X` and `Y` arguments as well:

```
WinMove, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1, , 200, 100, 1150, 750
```